# Obtain values from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a simple app which is checking occurrences of values. If there is already occurrences which I am looking for, it display that. If not, it adds.

```
create table Strings
(
    StringID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , StringValue VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

create table Links
(
    LinkID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Occurences
(
    OccurenceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,StringID INT NOT NULL
    ,LinkID INT NOT NULL
)
```

Class:

```
private SqlConnection conn;


public void Open()
{
    this.conn = new SqlConnection();
    this.conn.ConnectionString = @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=example;User=sa;Pwd=example;";
    this.conn.Open();
}

public void Close()
{
    this.conn.Close();
}


public string Obtain(string code)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=example;User=sa;Pwd=example;";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = code;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    sqlDataReader.Read();
    string result = sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    sqlConnection.Close();
    return result;
}


public void Insert(string StringID, string LinkID)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=example;User=sa;Pwd=example;";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = string.Concat(new string[]
    {
        "INSERT INTO Occurences VALUES ('",
        StringID,
        "', '",
        LinkID,
        "')"
    });
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        sql.Open();
        StringID = sql.Obtain("SELECT StringID from dbo.Strings where StringValue='" + textBox1.Text + "'");
        LinkID = sql.Obtain("SELECT LinkID from dbo.Links where Link='" + textBox2.Text + "'");
        Occurence = sql.Obtain("SELECT OccurenceID from dbo.Occurences where StringID='" + StringID + "' and LinkID = '" + LinkID + "'");
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Occurence) > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Occurence);
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        sql.Insert(StringID, LinkID);
    }

    finally
    {
        sql.Close();



    }
}
```

Is this coded well? Should I change my `catch` to more specific? Should I do something like these?

1. If there is no `StringValue` in `dbo.Strings` then insert `StringValue`
2. If there is no `Link` in `dbo.Links` then insert `Link`

Comment: What if the put  aa'; drop table Links in TextBox1

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries, not open and close three times to get 3 items,  and you don't need a reader to get one value.

Comment: For the sql connection, shouldn't you be using  "using" keyword that implicitly calls IDisposable or maybe use try..catch to explicitly call Dispose().

Comment: FYI "Occurences" is spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when we do something similar we use a repository (pattern). It allows us to encapsulate the entire interaction with the database so that we don't have to think about the queries again and again.

For example:

```
class MyDatabase
{
    public MyDatabase(string connectionString = null)
    {       
        // use the specified or the default connection string
        ConnectionString = connectionString ?? @"Server=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=example;User=sa;Pwd=example;";
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public int GetStringID(string stringValue)
    {
        // here comes the select and connection manintenance
    }
}
```

When working with database objects you should always use the `using` statement to free the resources. Always check the documentaiton if something implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Your actual code should look like this:

```
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    // work with the connection where
}
```

There are few more types that are disposable too (i.e. the `SqlCommand` or the `SqlDataReader`).

With the repository your `button1_Click` could look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new MyDatabase();
    StringID = db.GetStringID(textBox1.Text);
}
```

**Naming**

Even when working with the simplest projects you should always use meaningful names and `button1` or `textBox1` are really bad. I don't know what the button1 does but the text-box could be named `stringValueTextBox` or the `textBox2` should be called `linkTextBox` etc.